# Spreading column and replicating rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I do not know if my title for the question makes sense. I am trying to write a code that replace the count with the name of the columns. For example if the count of an observation has 2, the Id of that observation becomes 2 with the name of the column instead of the count. The tables below shows what I want if my explanation does not make sense.

This is my table (code):

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("P40", "P41", "P43"), 
                     Fruit = c(2, 2, 1),
                     Snack = c(2, 1, 1)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Table:

```
ID    Fruit Snack
P40     2     2
P41     2     1
P43     1     1

This is what i want to achieve:
 ID  Items 
P40  Fruit    
P40  Fruit
P40  Snack
P40  Snack
P41  Fruit
P41  Fruit
P41  Snack
P43  Fruit         
P43  Snack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to `gather` and `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
  uncount(value)

#     ID   key
#1   P40 Fruit
#1.1 P40 Fruit
#2   P41 Fruit
#2.1 P41 Fruit
#3   P43 Fruit
#4   P40 Snack
#4.1 P40 Snack
#5   P41 Snack
#6   P43 Snack
```

Comment: @ Ronak, this work perfectly on the sample (example) but when i use on a different dataset it gives me an error. Error in rep(seq_nrow(data), w) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: @ranaz How many columns do you have? Are they all numeric except `ID` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` by `unlist`ing the columns except the first one and then `rep`licating the sequence of rows with the values of the column to expand the data

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = df[,1], Items = unlist(df[-1], use.names = FALSE))
df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Items),]
#.    ID Items
#1   P40     2
#1.1 P40     2
#2   P41     2
#2.1 P41     2
#3   P43     1
#4   P40     2
#4.1 P40     2
#5   P41     1
#6   P43     1
```

Answer (score 0):

a one-liner:

```
library(reshape2)

dd <- data.frame(ID = rep(melt(df)$ID, melt(df)$value),
           Items = rep(melt(df)$variable,melt(df)$value)
           )
```